# material-ui setErrorText not working in material-ui 0.11

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the error text for a material-ui textfield via the field's method `setErrorText`, but when I do no error text I pass as an argument shows up. I see if you have the `errorText` property set on the component and try to use the `setErrorText` method it will error out: `Cannot call TextField.setErrorText when errorText is defined as a property.` but if I remove that property and try to use the method, again nothing shows up under the textfield component and no errors are present in the console log.

Is there something I'm missing or is this an issue that got shipped with this version?

Comment: I tested here with material-ui 0.13.4 and it seems to work. Without seeing your code it is difficult to say if there is something wrong.

Comment: show us your code so we can help you further.